# how should I build onClick action in my react component + Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been through many tutorials and questions on Stack but I can't find a solution. I'm just learning React/redux, trying to build OnClick action. I've got the following error `"Maximum call stack size exceeded error"`. I got this because I'm rendering a function that's changing my state infinitely. I'm trying to deal with my `<button onClick={DisplayTable(click)}>cool</button>` differently but nothing seems to work.
I also know that my action and I guess my reducers works properly since when I'm dispatching my action trough the console : `$r.store.dispatch({type: 'SET_TABLE_DATA'});`, my state is updated properly.

Any advices ?

here is my action :

```
export const setTableFilter = (click) => {
  return {
    type: 'SET_TABLE_DATA',
    click : click,
  };
};
```

here is my reducer :

```
const tableFilter = (state = 0, action) => {
    if(action.type === 'SET_TABLE_DATA') {
        return state + 1;
    }
        return state;
  }
```

and here is my component :

```
const DisplayTable = (click) => {

        return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={DisplayTable(click)}>cool</button>
        </div> )
    }


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
      click: state.tableFilter.click
  };
};


const mapDispachToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
  DisplayTable: (click) => {dispatch (setTableFilter(click));
        },
    };
};

const AppTable = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispachToProps)(DisplayTable);

export default AppTable;
```

I also know that I should build my reducer in a way that my state should be updated without any mutation, however I'll keep this for later ! :)

thanks.

Comment: Since you mentioned you are new the react, [you may find this site useful](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-react-counter-example?course=getting-started-with-redux)

Comment: I've done this tutorial thanks. It really help me to get the idea of what's a reducer, an action, and all... however when I'm trying to build the thing on my own it doesn't work...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer given doesn't really explain *why* your code was not working, so I thought I'd expand on that.

Your problem is that you are exceeding the function call stack, more commonly known as infinite recursion.  The reason this is happening is because you aren't passing a function to the `onClick` attribute of your button, but rather **invoking** a function and passing its return value instead.  So the following scenario is happening:

- React component is mounted to the DOM
- `render()` is called
- The `DisplayTable` function is invoked, which dispatches an update to the store
- The store updates, and passes new props to the React component
- `render()` is called again
- `DisplayTable` is invoked again

...and so on.

What you'll want to do instead is pass the function to the button's `onClick` attribute.  So your component should look like this:

```
const Component = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={props.DisplayTable}>cool</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

In that above code snippet, I removed your `click` prop because it doesn't look like you're using it at all (given the code you posted in the OP).

Comment: Ok thanks. You really frame my issue (besides the fact I'm learning :)). However when applying your snipper got this back `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` . I guess that's because my props is an empty object ?

Comment: I'd probably have to see more code to know where exactly you're going wrong.  Perhaps you could throw together an example in [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/?html,output)?

Comment: The only problems I see are that you're using `mapStateToProps` to define a `click` prop that doesn't exist on your state, and you're still requiring a `click` parameter in your `DisplayTable` function when you aren't calling it with an argument.

Comment: Ok. I cleaned all this a bit and now I can see the state updated when I'm clicking on my redux dev tool :) I'll try to move on with all this ! thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A few tips, not a complete solution since that would not help you learn:

Your action and reducer are looking fine. You are passing the *click* property which is not used in the reducer. Maybe you will use it in the future but for now it is useless.

A React component function takes props as an argument:

```
const Comp = props => {
    const click = props.click;
    // ...
};
```

`mapDispatchToProps` is usually not needed. Use plain objects instead:

```
connect(state => state.tableFilter, { setTableFilter })(DisplayTable);
```

You can then access the function from props:

```
<button onClick={() => props.setTableFilter(click)}>cool</button>
```

Keep in mind: `onClick` takes a function!

Also the state you defined in the reducer has no property called *click*, instead it is a number (see correct mapStateToProps function above)

Comment: *Sometimes* it is not needed.  The reason for this is because the second argument to `connect` can be either a function that returns an object, or just an object, with each key assumed to be an action creator.  If you use an object, it will be wrapped in a dispatch call anyways.  Either method is perfectly fine.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try all this, but I've already a first question why mapDispatchToProps usually is not needed ? ( that will maybe really help me to understand the purpose of this thing.)

Comment: In your case, passing a function to `connect` was not needed, since you could instead pass an object that references your action creators.  So you're still passing props to your component that can dispatch actions to the store, you're just doing it a different way.  Like I said, there's really no difference between the two.  If you're more comfortable using the `mapDispatchToProps` function, go right ahead.

Comment: @Herku, did you mean to write? `<button onClick={() => props.setTableFilter(click)}>cool</button>`

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen yes sure, I corrected that in the answer. This answer is very old actually and I am not even sure if there are any good practices left here. This is just an answer to the typical case where someone wants to learn 5 things at once, gets stuck and then goes to SO to get help. When you do 5 things wrong its hard to fix it. The important part is the arrow function I guess.